# Whey am I getting a Bad Request error while using Stockgeist API in accordance with their docs?

Tags: rest, python-requests

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

# API endpoint
url = "https://api.stockgeist.ai/stock/us/hist/message-metrics"

# API Key
headers = {
    'API Key': 'KEY IS HERE'
}

# List of tickers
tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT']

for ticker in tickers:

    # Query parameters
    params = {
        'symbols': str(ticker), 
        'start': '2023-07-01T00:00:00',  
        'end': '2023-07-02T00:00:00',      
}

    try:
        # Send the request
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

        # Check the response status code
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Convert the response to JSON
            data = response.json()

            # Convert the 'data' part of the response into a pandas DataFrame
            df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'])

            # Make directory if it does not exist
            if not os.path.exists('Project-3'):
                os.makedirs('Project-3')

            # Save the DataFrame as a CSV file
            df.to_csv(f'Project-3/{ticker}-s.csv', index=False)
        else:
            print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
            print(response.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

https://docs.stockgeist.ai/#get-/-asset_class-/-location-/hist/message-metrics

In this code I submit a request to pull sentiment data and whenever I do so I get a Bad Request error and it prints this:

```
Request failed with status code 400
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.5</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried making the header the normal Authorization Bearer but then I encounter Authentication errors (401).

I tried messing with the authentication and the parameters.

I was expecting it to return a json with the requested data